# Moving a MDToolbar in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i don't know how to move the toolbar to the top of the screen, before when i was creating a toolbar it was placed at the top of the screen by default. How can i fix this problem?
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsTlP.png)

```py
KV = ('''
Screen: 

    MDToolbar:
        title: "WeatherApp"
            
    MDLabel: 
        text: "Hello World"
''')


class WeatherApp(MDApp):

    Window.size = (350, 630)
    
    def build(self):

        self.title = "WeatherApp"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

WeatherApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Screen` as your `root` widget (also a parent of `MDToolbar`), which is a subclass of `FloatLayout`, you have to explicitly set any widget's position, otherwise all will be stacked on each other at (0, 0), *the default position*.

So if you want it to be placed on the top, use attr. `pos_hint` as,

```py
Screen: 

    MDToolbar:
        title: "WeatherApp"
        pos_hint: {"top" : 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have full control over widgets on the screen you could use RelativeLayout but computing the exact position might be a lil complicated but easy when you get it

```
Screen: 
    RelativeLayout:
        MDToolbar:
            y: self.parent.height - self.height
            title: "WeatherApp"
```

in RelativeLayout y defaults to 0 and x defaults to 0 which places the widget at the bottom left of the screen

The y property applies on the bottom of the widget so if you set

```
y: dp(30)
```

means the bottom of the widget is dp(30) from the bottom of the screen

same with the x property.

x applies on the left end of the widget. so if you set `x: dp(10)` it means the left end of the widget is dp(10) from the left end of the screen

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix until you add more items just add a `Widget` in-between your `MDToolbar` and `MDLabel` or after your `MDLabel`, for example:

```
KV = ('''
Screen: 
    MDToolbar:
        title: "WeatherApp"

    Widget:
        
    MDLabel: 
        text: "Hello World"
''')


class WeatherApp(MDApp):

Window.size = (350, 630)

def build(self):
    self.title = "WeatherApp"
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
    return Builder.load_string(KV)

WeatherApp().run()
```